# 120 A fusible link keeps on blowing on 2008 Sentra

Tags: electrical, nissan, fuse, sentra, no-crank-no-start

My wife was driving our 2008 Nissan Sentra when suddenly the car shut down while driving.

I noticed the 120 A battery fuse link popped, so I ordered a new one and put it in and popped again. The car doesn't start because of this.

What should I do to diagnose this problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated and will donate if helped, thanks.